# ESLint: Configuration to have conditional operators at the start of each line of multiline conditions

Tags: format, eslint, lint, typescript-eslint

Is there a way to tell ESLint to keep this:

```js
if (
   …
   && … 
   && …
)
```

Instead of this:

```js
if (
   …
   … &&
   … &&
)
```

(I like to have the operators at the beginning to be able to comment out different conditions easily)

---

ESLint config:

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
    plugins: ['svelte3', '@typescript-eslint'],
    ignorePatterns: ['*.cjs'],
    overrides: [{ files: ['*.svelte'], processor: 'svelte3/svelte3' }],
    settings: {
        'svelte3/typescript': () => require('typescript')
    },
    parserOptions: {
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaVersion: 2020
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2017: true,
        node: true
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your ESLint config?

Comment: @GOTO0 Good point, added it to the question

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. With your configuration, both styles pass validation. Maybe you have some additional rule like `operator-linebreak` enabled somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `"before"` option of `operator-linebreak` rule.
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/operator-linebreak#before

You can also use the `"overrides"` option if you want to set the style per operator.
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/operator-linebreak#overrides 
[DEMO](https://eslint.org/play/#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)